# pymongo : Unable to connect to mongolab

Tags: python, pymongo, mlab

I am getting this error while trying to connect to mongolab. I am using pymongo-2.8 as mentioned in some of other answers.

```
 connection=MongoClient("mongodb://usr:pass@host:port/data")
```

StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\chrome_addon\database_update.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection=MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@host:port/data")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 377, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
[Finished in 1.6s with exit code 1]
```

I also tried accessing it with command line, it is failing.

```
mongo ds031711.mongolab.com:31711/data -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

Stacktrace:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: ds031711.mongolab.com:31711/data
2015-10-02T10:40:21.662+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 54.159.76.238:31711
, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine act
ively refused it.
2015-10-02T10:40:21.670+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server ds0317
11.mongolab.com:31711 (54.159.76.238), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

URI and username,password are correct.

Comment: What if you would upgrade pymongo to the latest version and try again? `pip install --upgrade pymongo`

Comment: I did that. some answers say that pymongo has issues in their latest version.

Comment: Learn to use the [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/). ECONNREFUSED has absolutely nothing to do with Python. Using a shell which only talks to the database is kinda like checking if the machine is plugged in.

Comment: Alright but thats not the problem, why can't I access it using pymongo

Comment: Try this: 

 `connection=MongoClient("mongodb://usr:pass@host:port")
 db = connection['data']`

Comment: no. it is not working

Comment: how about `db = connection.data` and in that case where is it failing while creating client or while getting DB handle